# how to convert Curl command to python request using python scripts programatically

Tags: python, curl

I am trying to convert curl commands to python requests using python scripts. I could find the uncurl modules and could use it to convert few curl commands successfully. But I am facing issues to make my script generic for all curl commands. Following issues are holding back my work. I am trying to write the utility in python which will take curl commands from the text file and will convert commands to python requests one by one.

1. Commands types like GET / POST etc are not accepted by uncurl.
2. Curl command options like `-u` , `-X` etc are rejected.
3. For DELETE requests, how should I use uncurl.

curl -v -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "sync_id: 00000000-
0000-0000-0000-000000000001" -H "sync_token: 
NhbSzPhbtFlZ9Gm1nLr5f8e0WLGQitG4o00jb006m5Vcs00XVqzRdHcFtyv4YOzd5S02Z3x1iR5OWQINgLP2Og" -H "instance_id: instance_id"  -X GET 'example.com'
curl -v -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "sync_id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001" -H "sync_token: NhbSzPhbtFlZ9Gm1nLr5f8e0WLGQitG4o00jb006m5Vcs00XVqzRdHcFtyv4YOzd5S02Z3x1iR5OWQINgLP2Og" -H "instance_id: instance_id" -X POST -d '[{"id":"1", "name":"1", "env_mapping_name":"a", "env_mapping_id":"a1"}]' example.com'

The python code which I used for convertsion.

```
import uncurl
command = 'curl -v -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "sync_id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001" -H "sync_token: NhbSzPhbtFlZ9Gm1nLr5f8e0WLGQitG4o00jb006m5Vcs00XVqzRdHcFtyv4YOzd5S02Z3x1iR5OWQINgLP2Og" -H "instance_id: instance_id"  -X GET 'example.com'

print uncurl.parse(command)
```

I have stripped off the tags and curl options which were giving me exceptions as follows.

```
def stripTags(command):
    '''Strip off the unwanted tags from the curl command'''
    print '\nCommand is *********************************', command

    command = command.replace('-X', '')
    command = command.replace('-k', '')
    command = command.replace('-v', '')
    command = command.replace(' \'', ' \"')
    command = command.replace('\' ', '\" ')
    command = command.replace('\'', '\"')
    command = command.replace(' GET ', '')
    command = command.replace(' POST ', '')
    command = command.replace(' PUT ', '')
    command = command.replace(' POST ', '')
    command = command.replace(' DELETE ', '')
    print '\nStripped string is =============', command
    return command
```

When I used the following curl command for conversion, I got an exception.

> 'curl -v --proxy-user "00dcf6e7-4513-4e46-bbaf-ef4cac8f8d47":"XUmh8pIG68Zo" -X GET "example.com" --proxy 127.0.0.1:8080 -k'

The `-U` option here is bothering. Likewise there are other options which I observed exceptions on. So I am not sure if I am using uncurl correctly or not.
All the curl commands are converted when I used online convertor from curl.trillworks.com. 
Can you please provide me the pointer on how to convert curl commands in to python requests?

**** :- I could able to send the curl command using 'runcurl' package. As per my understanding, the uncurl package has limitation of sending the curl request which the runcurl bridges by providing the 'execute' method. I used the following code to do so. 
 
   `import runcurl
   cmd = "curl -v -u "00dcf6e7-4513-4e46-bbaf-ef4cac8f8d47":"XUmh8pIG68Zo" -X GET "https://example.com" -k"
    #strip off the curl options like -k, -v, -X, GET which causes runcurl to    #throw exception. 
    try:
        code = runcurl.execute(command)
    except:
        code = 400
        //Write the failed cases in some file for further references`

As earlier, I have to strip off the options supported by curl like '-k', '-v'. In the above curl command, the option for authentication is provided with the '-u' option. But the runcurl is throwing an exception. 
I am seeking help on this point. My expectation is that 'runcurl' should not error out for the required options supported by curl. For ex:- '-u' option. Did I miss anything here? Is there any better way of handling curl command above? 
**Note** :- I am trying to avoid the use of 'subprocess.call()' to call the curl command in my code.

Comment: maybe this helps? https://curl.trillworks.com/ (and if you want serious answers please post some code; show what you have tried and ask a precise question about where you are stuck).

Comment: Thanks hiro.                                                                                                I have already checked the site you mentioned. The curl commands are getting converted on the mentioned online converter. What I am looking here is the mechanism / code in python to convert the curl commands in python requests. Here are the details of what I have done so far and at what point I am stuck.

Comment: with details i meant code (a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: <Curl commands >                                                                                curl -v -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "sync_id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001" -H "sync_token: NhbSzPhbtFlZ9Gm1nLr5f8e0WLGQitG4o00jb006m5Vcs00XVqzRdHcFtyv4YOzd5S02Z3x1iR5OWQINgLP2Og" -H "instance_id: instance_id"  -X GET 'https://ucreporting-sync-api-dev.mybluemix.net/api/v1/ucd/missedcprs'
</Curl Commands>

Comment: <code>                                                                                                    import uncurl                                                                             uncurl.parse(command)                                                                  </code>

Comment: people here will not write code for you. show what you have tried (not in the comments, in the question). and with tried i mean the python part. please have a look at how other people ask questions (and do thake the tour). the way you ask it right now i'm almost certain nobody will answer.

Comment: The code worked for command. But it threw exception when command contains '-U' option. I have already stripped off the tags like -X, -k, -v using python and could get the above command converted using uncurl. So I am looking for the help in understanding how do I direct uncurl to handle curl supported options to convert command in python requests.

Comment: By the way, I have checked the link you provided on how to ask questions on the forum. Thanks for the link. I hope , the data I provided is adequate enough to provide pointers on the topic.